# Execute program with another ip interface

Tags: linux, ip

My server has several ip interfaces. I want to execute a script that fetches a webpage content and i was wondering if its possible to use another ip interface besides the default one. The script does not have an interface argument like curl.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible.. But it's dirty.

http://www.ryde.net/code/bind.c.txt

1) Compile it to a shared object:

`cc -nostartfiles -fpic -shared bind.c -o bind.so -ldl -D_GNU_SOURCE`

2) Set the BIND_ADDR variable, and the LD_PRELOAD path and execute your application, as follows.
`BIND_ADDR="127.0.0.1" LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so /path/to/your/application`

3) Your application now has the interface as the default.

Comment: will this change the default server interface? I mean the change will be isolated in the program right?

Comment: Yes, the change is isolated to the program run in the environment where LD_PRELOAD was set to bind.so

Answer (score 0):

w/o touching your script, you would need to change the default interface for the whole system - which is most likely not a good idea!

I suggest you to update `the script` and make it to use the interface you want... it can be done eg. by specifying `--bind-address` if you're using `wget`